# What is the best AMI to use in Amazon for a Ruby server?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ruby

I have previously installed instances of Amazon EC2 servers. I know that it takes a while to get MySQL, Postgres, Rubygems, Ruby, etc.. installed on the server.

I'm wondering if there is a better way. For example, getting started with an existing/public AMI out there.

If so, what's the most complete AMI for a server that will only run Ruby (Sinatra/Rails with Postgres or MySQL) applications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using one of the Ubuntu AMIs, it's as simple as

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server postgresql ruby rubygems rails
```

Or if you're using Fedora or CentOS or Red Hat, it will probably be

```
sudo yum install mysql-server postgresql ruby rubygems rails
```

If you go to Amazon EC2 - Navigation - Images - AMIs and search for Public Images containing the word "ruby" you will find AMIs with names such as

- rubysquickstart (by Amazon)
- rubystack
- rubyonrails

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can get both EBS and S3-backed AMIs for Rails at [BitNami](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack)